# How to save a contour of an image as another image?

Tags: python

I am trying to take contour of an image and rotate that contour alone. so I want to store the contour as a separate image. please help me with the code and thanks in advance:)

Comment: Please post what you have tried and any related code

Comment: where is your code you are asking help with?